# How can I edit my code to include a method

Tags: java, loops, methods

How can I edit my code to include a method, call it rollDice(), to return the generated random integer number between 1 and 6? Thanks.

Here's my current code:

```
public class CrapsGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
      int dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
      int roll = dice1 + dice2;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("You rolled "+roll+". ");
      if(roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12){
         System.out.println("You lose");
      }
      else if(roll == 7 || roll == 11){
          System.out.println("You win");
      }
       else{
         System.out.println("point is "+roll+"\n");
         dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
         dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
         int roll2 = dice1 + dice2;
         System.out.print("You rolled "+roll2+". ");
         while(roll2 != 7){
            if(roll == roll2){
               System.out.println("You win");
               break;
            }
            else{
               System.out.println("point is "+roll+"\n");
            }
            dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
            dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
            roll2 = dice1 + dice2;
            System.out.print("You rolled "+roll2+". ");
         }
         if(roll2 == 7){
             System.out.println("You lose");
         }          
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You were be able to write all this, but you don't know how to create a method? And you haven't found any help by reading other questions on  StackOverflow or one of those thousends of Java tutorials?

Comment: I'm currently learning methods, I've already worked with loops before.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CrapsGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int dice1 = rollDice();
      (...)
   }

   private static int rollDice() {
      return (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: that method should be static

Comment: I keep getting an illegal start of expression error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I seemed to get it to work when adding the rollDice() method before the main string. Can anyone explain why that is?

Comment: In some programming languages this may be an issue, but in Java the order of methods and variables makes no difference.